# Represent format of the date 2018-01-01T17:11:11.111+06:00 in string

Tags: scala, elasticsearch, datetime-format, elastic4s

How can I represent format of `2018-01-01T17:11:11.111+06:00` in string?
I've tried `yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS+HH:mm`, but it didn't work.
It is needed for range query in elasticsearch using elastic4s.

Comment: look at here https://esddd.herokuapp.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let' try:

```
YYYY-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSz
```

I suggest to you this app for check the format:

https://esddd.herokuapp.com/